# Terminal: UTF8 chars "overlapping" even with fixed width font

Tags: utf-8, terminal

I was doing a visualization in this years [adventofcode](http://adventofcode.com). My first stab just used plain ascii chars [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuEnRBrcdiA). Then I saw this image [image]

Which I thought was really nice. However, when I attempted to put in these chars, they completely overlapped.

[image]

Is there a nice way to do this? I've tried installing [gnu unifont](http://www.unifoundry.com/unifont.html) as that sounded like a decent start, but no joy.

How do I use the terminal to print "letters" like this and have them come out nicely? I might be missing something fundamental about terminals + UTF8. If it matters, I'm using OSX terminal app, [Anonymice Powerline Nerd Font Complete Mono font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/patched-fonts/AnonymousPro/complete/Anonymice%20Powerline%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete%20Mono.ttf).

EDIT

Yes, the font didn't contain items which were encoded correctly (or was falling back?! if that's even possible, to items which weren't encoded correctly)

I ended up using [the symbola font](http://www.fonts2u.com/symbola.font) which, while not perfect, means I can draw this:

[image]

which is good enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the "patched font" didn't set the font metrics properly.  Terminals expect the font header to give a bounding box which applies to all characters.  If the individual glyphs don't fall into the box, you'll get interesting effects like this.

Comment: I imagine it's something like that, however, when I tried the gnu unifont the still overlapped. I'll leave this as not-the answer for a bit. I don't suppose you know of a font which _should_ work do you?